# Mercurial Netbeans Output file not tracked!

Tags: netbeans, mercurial, tortoisehg

I'm using Mercurial in Netbeans, everything worked fine until I got this message:

`Output: [abort: helper.php: file not tracked!]`

I remember that I renamed this file once from outside Netbeans (file directory rename), it was Helper.php (with H instead of h).

I set it back to Helper.php from Netbeans and from file directory, still same message:

`Output: [abort: helper.php: file not tracked!]`

How can I add this file again so it's tracked with the rest of the files?

Answer (score 4):

I think just had the same problem. I've just renamed the file through *cmd* and back again to my real (desired) name and problem disappeared.

```
> hg rename myname.java someothername.java
> hg rename someothername.java myname.java
```

Answer (score 2):

What does does output of `hg stat` and `hg summary` look like on the command line?  What OS are you on?  It could be a [Case Folding](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/CaseFolding) thing, or just that you need to tell Mercurial you renamed that file using `hg rename --after`.

Comment: where to write `hg stat` ? (sorry I'm noob)

Comment: From your command line.  If you have Mercurial installed you'll have the `hg` command and the output of `hg stat` and `hg summary` will tell us everything we need to know.

Comment: I right clicked on helper.php and went to hg->rename and renamed it to Helper.php then helper.php nothing changed

Comment: Yeah, that (doing something) would be the opposite of what I suggested (investigating further).  Good luck.